# What angle do I insert iPad SIM eject tool into new iPad to get the tray out?

Tags: sim, eject, ipad

I've found lots of videos on how to eject the SIM card holder from an iPad 2, but the location is different on the New iPad, and no matter whether to put the pin in parallel to the screen surface, or at the sort of angle shown on the card that holds the SIM eject tool, I just can't seem to make the the card holder actually eject!

I haven't yet been able to find any video demos online, yet, for the new iPad.

I'd appreciate any tips, to avoid my breaking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### PUSH!

The old way was to insert the tool at an angle and kind of push sideways and *pull out* at the same time, using *leverage*, and the tray would hang onto and come out with the tool, but with the new iPad (2012), simply insert the SIM eject tool straight into the tiny hole (straight being the way it enters with the least resistance, i.e. perpendicular to the case where the hole is), and then **push**.  The tray will eject.

I'd have posted a link to authoritative information, but I just had this exact problem myself (UPS guy arrived an hour ago!) and so I'm speaking from first-hand experience :-)

I tried what I thought was obvious once I realized the hole was *no longer* part of the SIM card tray assembly (see photos below), so angling and pulling would do nothing like it did on the 2010 model's tray (i.e. when the hole was *part of* the tray).

- SIM card tray outer view from my original iPad (2010):

   [image: SIM card tray outer view from my original iPad (2010)]
  ***Notice the hole was part of the tray.***
- SIM card tray outer view from my new iPad (2012):

   [image: SIM card tray outer view from my new iPad (2012)]
  ***Notice the hole is separate from the tray.***  Insert SIM tool, and **push**.

I'm adding a comment.
Once you notice the Sim Tray lifting just a fraction you are half way there - now push harder and it pops right out. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I did eventually get it to work, but couldn't figure out how to describe it in words. This says it well.

Comment: The key thing is that the pin/tool should be at about 45 degrees to horizontal, i.e. roughly perpendicular to the case where the hole is.  And you have to press quite hard.  It would be good if you could emphasise the angle in your answer, as the question is about the angle.

Comment: This is not true, it has been a straight 'push' since the original iPhone. Not like you say: "The old way was to insert the tool at an angle and kind of push sideways and pull out at the same time, using leverage, and the tray would hang onto and come out with the tool"

Answer (score 1):

The eject tool must be at an angle (slihgtly larger than 45 degrees). I just did it on my "new" iPad bought at Apple store in April 2012.

Apple support pages have [instructions for the iPad 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4577). I could not find instructions specific for the new iPad, but the information in the previous link seems (to me) to be applicable.

Comment: You do have to push quite hard to get the tray to eject - as long as you are at about 45 degrees to horizontal, it's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

just tilt the pin a 'lil bit push and feel it,then pop.....